# How come I can't publish this to my user's Facebook wall?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like

I got the access_token (with email, publish_stream, and offline_access permissions).

Then, I do this code:

```
var uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + req.user.fb.id + '/feed';
    request({   'method':'POST',
                'uri':uri,
                'json':{
                    'access_token':req.user.fb.accessToken,
                    'message':'testing 123',
                },
            },
     function(err,response,body){
     console.log(err);
     console.log(body);

    });
```

But facebook gives me this error message:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id."}}
```

I don't get it? The user logged in perfectly fine using facebook connect, and I got the access token.

Comment: Are you providing a valid app_id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to send the access_token as part of the query string, not as the post body.

```
var uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + req.user.fb.id + '/feed?access_token=' + req.user.fb.accessToken;
```